# How java references work when passing method parameters

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public void synchronized method1(Class_Instance_Variables instanceVar, int classprimitive)
public void method2(Class_Instance_Variables instanceVar, int classprimitive)
```

When passing parameters to method does java creates fresh reference to the methods or 
does it use existing reference to pass to the methods ?

**Thread-1** get the lock of synchronized method1 and pass "class instance variable" and class instance primitive variable.
**Thread-2** pass method2 pass same "class instance variable" and class instance primitive variable.

How the references work in this case ? Does it create a new reference for each passing?

Comment: Nope. This is not a duplicate. The question is relating to the references is it creating a new one or use existing reference.

Comment: How would you tell the difference between a fresh reference and the same reference? Why would it matter?

Comment: Read the question and answers. Unless you're not formulating your question right, this is an exact duplicate. The fact that threads and `synchronized` are involved is irrelevant.

Comment: In addition to the linked question, see also the official tutorial on [passing arguments to methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html). Whether or not a method is `synchronized` has no effect on how parameters are passed.

Answer (score 0):

A reference is just an address value (modulo the indirection inherent in heap management). Talking about the difference between two references is like talking about the difference between two integers -- outside of which memory location they occupy, if they're the same value there is NO difference between them.

You may be confused because you're assuming Java heap management is reference-counted, in which case references are independent objects. It isn't; Java uses mark/sweep GC, and a reference is just a pointer.

There are no "new references". There are just references. Threads or not.